# Can't access php values inside an object

Tags: php, oop, object

I have an object that has keys with '.' character inside them..

How can I access them properly using just the $var->site.title

Is there a way to do that, sticking to the object method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) syntax:

```
$obj->{"site.title"}
```

Comment: Thanks..! I tried $obj->{site.title} but I didn't think of that. You were so quick that I have to wait 9 minutes to accept the answer.. lol.. Again, thanks..